# Request to another page - Realise with header() or include?

Tags: php, header, include, request

In my project i'm using clean URL's and all requests will be forwarded to the index.php.
In the index.php i have a routing-aprt which checks the URL-Parameter in a switch/case-construct and includes the respective site.

But is include the right tool for this? Or should i use header() for this?

Comment: `include` is usually used to incorporate another script as a part of the current script, not as a total replacement. On the other hand, if you use a redirect the new URL becomes visible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `include` to conditionally run the PHP code based on URL.  `header` is for the content of the response, such as to send the user to another URL.

At the most basic level you could use a routing implementation [such as this](http://docforge.com/wiki/Clean_URL) in your index.php:

```
if ($_GET['q']) {
  // Break the request into it's path parts
  $path_parts = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
  $section = $path_parts[0];
}
else {
  $section = 'home';
}

switch ($section) {
  case 'home':
    // For requests to the home page
    require('home.html');
  case 'about':
    // For URLs like http://www.example.com/about
    require('about.html');
    break;
  case 'login':
    if (check_login()) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    }
    else {
        require('login.html');
    }
    break;
  case 'wiki':
    // For URLs like http://www.example.com/wiki/Document
    $page = empty($path_parts[1]) ? '' : $path_parts[1];
    require('wiki.php');
    break;
  default:
    // Unexpected page requests should get a 404
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    include('error.html');
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if i have in your example the case 'login', then normaly the controller call a method like checkLogin(). If login is successful, then the user should forwarded to (for example) the home-site. For this you use again include(). And here is the problem: If you are forwareded to the home-site, you still have in your URL the Login-URL....

Comment: For redirecting after "/login" you set header to redirect the user to home (e.g. "/"). The URL is now different for the next request and routed home. I've updated my code as an example.

Comment: But header() can't be used, if i put out HTML-code already (which i done by showing the login-page).

Comment: Please ready my code more carefully. The check for login (e.g. reading POST data and checking the DB) is done before any HTML is output. The user is redirected before you output anything back to them. More specifically, the login HTML is shown during the initial GET request. During the POST of the form you check and redirect if it's good.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use some simple routing class that will load controllers based on your url + autoloader to include controller classes.

Answer (score 1):

forward page link use this

```
<?php 

header("location:index.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is used to manipulate the raw http header. I.E. header("Location: http://www.google.com")

[include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is used to include and evaluate a particular file. In other words, the variables and functions in the included file are available to the application at that point.

So, you would want an include for your intentions, I believe. If I understand you correctly.